# How to check if opencv is using GPU or not?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu

I need to know if the current opencv installation is using GPU or not. I tried `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` but this is not what I'm looking for. I also tried `getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` this doesn't work and throws error too.

Answer (score 30):

If you have installed **cuda**, there's a built-in function in **opencv** which you can use now.

```
import cv2
count = cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
print(count)
```

`count` returns the number of installed CUDA-enabled devices.

You can use this function for handling all cases.

```
def is_cuda_cv(): # 1 == using cuda, 0 = not using cuda
    try:
        count = cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
        if count > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except:
        return 0
```

Tested with opencv `4.2.0`

Comment: please, don't post screenshots of text screens, post the text itself (copy / paste etc)

Comment: I have already posted the relevant code, the screenshot was just to demonstrate my opencv version as trying this on a lower version may not work. Should I remove it?

Comment: if you are able to copy / paste the contents instead of the screen shot -- the picture has to go =)